# AudioKit Start Weird sounds plays with AKFMOscillator

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I upgraded AudioKIt to `4.3` using cocoa pods and got some issues related to sounds. When I start AudioKIt it plays some weird sounds for one second. Can someone please help me to solve this issue? Below is my code.

```
oscillator = AKFMOscillator()
oscillator!.amplitude = 0.0  
oscillator!.baseFrequency = Double(calibration.frequency)
oscillator!.carrierMultiplier = 1.0
oscillator!.modulatingMultiplier = HolmesMethod.warbleModulationFrequency / Double(calibration.frequency)
oscillator!.modulationIndex = HolmesMethod.warbleModulationIndex
oscillator!.rampDuration = HolmesMethod.clickMillis / 1000.0


panner = AKPanner(oscillator, pan: calibration.channel == .Right ? 1.0 : -1.0)
AudioKit.output = panner
do {
    try AudioKit.start()
    } catch  {
}

oscillator!.start()
panner?.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting weird sounds for a full second or do you just mean a "moment" because you are ramping up to your values.  You can also initialize the parameter inside the AKFMOscillator initialization if you want to start from those values.

Comment: Not for a full second but may be 0.5 second sound. When i put timer for 0.5 to start scaillator it works fine but don't need because app is depends on other timer as well. What do you mean by initialize the parameter inside the AKFMOscillator initialization??